# « Même si j’appréhendais » ou « Même si je l'appréhendais »

Tags: expressions, dialogues

Je cherche à retranscrire un dialogue, puis-je utiliser cette formulation ?

> Même si j’appréhendais, je rêvais de pouvoir vivre ce moment.

Comment: Pourriez-vous nous fournir la phrase originale ?

Comment: Appréhender est transitif donc je dirais : "même si je l'appréhendais"

Comment: @Guillaume: les emplois intransitifs existent aussi (cf. [les exemples](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/appr%C3%A9hender) du Wiktionnaire, par exemple). Mais c'est vrai que l'utiliser sans complément aucun laisse peut-être une touche de langage populaire.

Comment: Une autre formulation avec le subst. : « Malgré mes appréhensions, je rêvais de ce moment. »

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si tu cherches à dire que c'est le moment que tu appréhendes, il me semble préférable effectivement de spécifier le complément. La phrase complète serait alors :

> Même si j'appréhendais *ce moment*, je rêvais de pouvoir vivre *ce moment*.

Il est bien évident qu'il faut remplacer le complément par un pronom dans une des deux propositions. Je suggère deux possibilités :

> Même si je l'appréhendais, je rêvais de pouvoir vivre ce moment.

ou :

> Même si j'appréhendais ce moment, je rêvais de pouvoir le vivre.

Comme l'a dit plus tôt @StéphaneGimenez, il est possible de trouver des usages d'« appréhender » sans complément (cf. [les exemples du Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/appr%C3%A9hender)), mais ceux-ci laissent une sensation d'incomplétude lorsque le verbe est utilisé dans le sens de « craindre ».

On peut trouver « J'appréhende. » à l'oral en tant que phrase complète, lorsque les interlocuteurs savent clairement de quoi il est sujet (je suis coupable de ceci), mais c'est effectivement du langage oral et populaire, qui me semble incorrect et à mon avis n'est pas à retenir dans le contexte de la phrase que tu proposes.

Comment: Très bonne réponse! Franchement les pronoms en français sont les plus difficiles pour moi de saisir. J'imagine qu'ils posent des gros problèmes même pour les francophones!

Comment: Le français est une langue difficile, combinant beaucoup de règles et beaucoup d'exceptions. Il est vrai que les pronoms utilisés et leur placement peut varier d'un contexte à un autre, mais la plupart des francophones grandissent en utilisant uniquement cette langue et cela leur semble un peu plus naturel qu'à un non-francophone cherchant à apprendre le français.

Comment: Ouais t'as raison. Le même problème existe en anglais aussi, concernant les pronoms. Les prépositions de plus J'ai des difficultés en expliquant quand on peut les utiliser, et quand on ne peut pas. Contrairement aux verbes, noms, adjectifs, etc, les mots de la 'classe fermée' comme les prépositions, pronoms etc posent toujours des problèmes pour ceux qui apprennent la langue comme deuxième, troisième etc, moi inclu!

Comment: @Chop merci pour tes superbes explications !

Comment: @ChrisCirefice même pour des français...